# NCE loss in word2vec vs a common Neural Network

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, nlp, word2vec

As I was trying to learn more about NLP, I realized that people use NCE loss without defining a connected NN. To be more specific:

```
# Define Embeddings:
embeddings = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([vocabulary_size, embedding_size], -1.0, 1.0))

# NCE loss parameters
nce_weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([vocabulary_size, embedding_size],
                                               stddev=1.0 / np.sqrt(embedding_size)))
nce_biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([vocabulary_size]))

# Create data/target placeholders
x_inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[batch_size])
y_target = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[batch_size, 1])
valid_dataset = tf.constant(valid_examples, dtype=tf.int32)

# Lookup the word embedding:
embed = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, x_inputs)

# Get loss from prediction
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.nce_loss(weights=nce_weights,
                                     biases=nce_biases,
                                     labels=y_target,
                                     inputs=embed,
                                     num_sampled=num_sampled,
                                     num_classes=vocabulary_size))
```

Instead, why do people not define a connected NN, and a with sigmoid as the activation function in the final layer? Would my suggestion be considered as doable if we were to use one-hot encoding, and not relevant in most-frequent value representation? I am sorry if my question is a bit dumb since I am not so much familiar with NLP yet.

Thanks

Comment: Not related to programming, better suited for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) sister site.

Comment: @desertnaut I believe that this is a typical ML question. And since "machine-learning" tag exists, it could belong here?

Comment: there are lots of diverging opinions on that... the consensus seems to be that here belong ML questions that have directly to do with *implementation/programming* issues, while questions of a more theoretical/conceptual flavor (such as yours) belong to CV... Anyway, nothing is written in stone, and this is just my advice - feel free to take it or not :)